# positiong carousal @ very top behind the nav bar

Tags: html, css

i have navbar then carousal below it,
my problem was the indicator was not display on screen and that because i guess the navbar push it just a little below i did some research and found that i need to do 
.my-carousal
position:absolute;
top:0px;

so it start its start from very top with the navbar and its fix the problem and its now on 100% screen width & height (navbar has z-index higher so its show above the carousal )

but now the section and content below the carousal is JUMP INSIDE the carousal and i tried many-things and i cant fix it.

navbar code:

http://prntscr.com/kk414g

carousal code:

http://prntscr.com/kk41gy

content below carousal:

http://prntscr.com/kk41rd

css code:
http://prntscr.com/kk42o7

index.html:

http://prntscr.com/kk43m5

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the carousel and the content after that in different div rows. It will separate them. Html code and Css could help giving more accurate answer to your problem.